# Use Cookies as a lock file in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I'd like to only allow users to be able to click a link once, like this one:

http://www.blah.com/download.php?file=zFZpj4b2AkEFz%2B3O

Each user has an e-mail sent with a unique link and when they click on it I'd like to set a cookie on the SERVER so I know to reject that link's access again.

Any ideas welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Cookies are stored on the client, so you can't do that. And what if there is a problem downloading the file?

Comment: if you really don't want users to click twice, you may create a record in db about the click event...

Comment: Internet explorer by default blocks downloads and once you click ok it refreshes the page your code would see this as a double click

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. It's for a viewing subscription of an event that might last for an hour or so. The name download.php is  a bit misleading. I've got the unique URL working with an expiry but I need a way of stopping someone sending a unique link to all of their friends and so I need to limit the number of accesses to one link. Any ideas ? I'm trying really hard not to use a DB because there are so many involved already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking duplicate download could cause issues (especially with internet explorers file blocker that causes a page refresh).

Cookies are the wrong answer because all the user has to do is use a different browser/machine or clear their cookies to redownload.

If you are desperate to do this how about

On the file system create a symbolic link to the real file and name the link the same as the key.

On processing the page request:

1. validate the url string (to avoid path jumping etc)
2. Check for the existence of this link, if it doesn't exist link is invalid/expired so show error
3. Otherwise, Copy file to response
4. Delete link

Comment: That sounds like a plan ! Thanks. What about creating a symlink the first time a unique link is used and then throwing up a "Already accessed" error if that exists ? I'm out of my league with filesystem stuff on PHP though. Any code snippets would be very welcome !

Comment: [PHP Manual on symlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php). You would need a way at somepoint to clean up all the extra symlinks you've created.  Also as you are preventing other people accessing the url you could additionally store the key in the users session as an override to allow them to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

On download.php check if the a cookie like AlreadyAccessed exists and if it exists deny the download otherwise start the download of file and set cookie. That's it

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are stored client-side, not server-side, so that's not the right option. If a user deletes your site's cookies, he'd be able to circumvent any check that is based on cookie existence/value.

You *could* create a file on the server with a specific name when you send the link, and remove it once it's been accessed. If someone tries to access the link a second time, the "flag" file will not exist and you'll know it's a repeat (or invalid) link.

(Would be better with a database though, file-based checks are hard to do in a non-racy manner.)

Comment: A random example from the Cherokee web server project:  http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_handlers_secdownload.html